# Error on Normalized Equation for Josephus Problem

Tags: c, josephus

```
//
//  main.c
//  단기 연구 과제
//  Created by Shiro Nai on 07/05/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Shiro Nai. All rights 
//  reserved.


#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    double n;

    printf("How many people?");
    scanf("%lf", &n);

    int k = floor(log10(n)/log10(2));

    printf("The last standing person's number is %lf.", (2*(n-(2^k)))+1);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is different from what I expected.
For example, when `n`=5 the answer is 3, but I get 11 for the output.

Comment: Do you know what `2^k` is? It is using the exclusive-or operator, but I guess you are raising to `2` to the power `k`?

Comment: I am surprised there is no canonical dupe for this

Comment: ^ is not being treated like a power-of operator, but rather an exclusive-or operator, which both do different things.

Comment: C has a [log2()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log2) function, btw.

Comment: You'll probably also be interested in [exp2()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp2).

Comment: Wait... I'm rusty, but isn't `exp2(log2(n))` just `n`?

Comment: Yes it is @Shawn, you are correct.

Comment: The `floor()` changes things though. Nevermind that attempt at simplification.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` symbol is not a power operator. This does not do any kind of math, this is an [exclusive-or](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/8514/----bitwise-xor--exclusive-or-) operator.

In order to do power calculations, you need `pow()` from `math.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    printf("The value of 11 ^ 3 = %.2f", pow(11.0, 3)); // outputs 1331.00
}
```

---

Sources:

- http://codeforwin.org/2017/08/bitwise-operators-c.html
- https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/8514/----bitwise-xor--exclusive-or-

Comment: You could point to the C standard better than some pages one of which says "cplusplus"